# Add image overlay for each millisecond the video using ffmpeg and php

Tags: php, windows, video, ffmpeg, frame

I need to add an image and different position for each millisecond the video frame, using php and ffmpeg.
For example:
In the first second I add an image in the X position, the next second another image in the position X.
If you use the command directly on the terminal, the conversion is successful. But in PHP I have difficulties.
In php, use the following command:

```
<?php
shell_exec('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\vid.mp4 -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=100:25:enable=\'between(t,1,1.5)\'"  C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output1.mp4');
sleep(20);
echo "1";
shell_exec('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output1.mp4 -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:25:enable=\'between(t,1.5,2)\'"  C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output2.mp4');
sleep(50);
echo "2";
shell_exec('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output2.mp4 -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\3.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=250:25:enable=\'between(t,2,2.5)\'"  C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output1.mp4');
sleep(20);
echo "3";
shell_exec('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output1.mp4 -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\4.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=300:25:enable=\'between(t,3,3.5)\'"  C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output2.mp4');
sleep(20);
echo "4";
shell_exec('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output2.mp4 -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\5.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=350:25:enable=\'between(t,4,4.5)\'"  C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output1.mp4');
sleep(70000);
shell_exec('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output1.mp4 -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=400:25:enable=\'between(t,5,5.5)\'"  C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output2.mp4');
```

I used the sleep function (PHP), but it did not work.
Please, as I have not much experience with ffmpeg and php, you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot by examining the command's output.  That should give you the answer.

```
exec('C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\vid.mp4 -i C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=100:25:enable=\'between(t,1,1.5)\'"  C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output1.mp4', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?